# Use Style from Application in External Controls

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

How can I use my application's styling on controls in a different project?

I have a VS solution with three projects; AndroidLib, the actual application and a library with custom controls for the application.

The application is styled with MahApps.Metro 14.0.0. I'd like to use this style with the controls from my control lib. However, whenever I add a custom control, the styles are the default.
When, however, I use the controls provided with WPF, the styles go back to MahApps.Metro.

Example:

```
<TabControl Margin="200, 30, 0, 0" >
        <TabItem x:Name="testListViewItem" Header="Test TabItem" />
</TabControl>
```

This works and uses the MahApps.Metro styling.
However:

```
<TabControl Margin="200, 30, 0, 0" >
        <dmailControls:EmailListViewTabItem x:Name="testListViewItem" Header="Test TabItem" />
</TabControl>
```

Shows, but it doesn't assume the styling from MahApps.Metro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the style for the `EmailListViewTabItem` than maybe you forgot to set the `MahApps` style for it.

You should use this at `App.xaml` to get the style for your custom `TabItem`.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type dmailControls:EmailListViewTabItem}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroTabItem}" />
```

Hope this helps.